# Does the dollar sign, when used in a string, mean anything special regarding arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Given this mongoose query, what does the dollar sign mean here?

```
customers.findOne({'name':data.tenant,'scripts.name':data.name},{'scripts.$':1},function(err,data2){
```

This ends up returning one element of the `scripts` array.

the dollar sign below work in the same way?

```
var newStr =  loc.replace(/(.*\/)[^/]+(\/[^\/]*)$/,'$1'+data.name+'$2');
```

`$1` and `$2` are the first and second elements of the array.

Does the `$` character, when used in a string, mean something special for arrays, indexes, or something like that?

Or is the `$` just overwritten and used in different ways by the `findOne`, and `string.replace` functions, respectively?

Comment: There's no language-wide meaning for `$`.

Comment: @Pointy "no" would be a valid answer that I would award points for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$1` is specific to replace() function as described before

`$` in database query is mongodb-specific token that means "array entry that matches your request", you can find it in mongodb docs

So no, there is no language-wide meaning of this symbol. It's sometimes used as a function name (jQuery), but it's just a regular literal, nothing special about it.

Comment: I've tried looking for that in the mongodb docs, but couldn't find it. If you know where it is, ca you link to it?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/ , "$ - Acts as a placeholder to update the first element that matches the query condition in an update."

Comment: I think this more matches my case: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Answer (score 1):

`$1` and `$2` are back references to your regex.

Given `var newStr =  loc.replace(/(.*\/)[^/]+(\/[^\/]*)$/,'$1'+data.name+'$2');`

`$1` refers to whatever is matched by the first set of parentheses

`$2` refers to whatever is matched by the second set of parentheses

Comment: Is this specific functionality constrained to the `replace` function, or can the dollar sign be used in a similar manner elsewhere?